# Java/Kotlin JSON parsing improvement

Tags: java, parsing, android, json, kotlin

I consume an API which gives me this type of JSON:

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "Start",
    "pid": "1",
    "position": {
      "data": {
        "x": "31",
        "y": "330"
      },
      "metadata": "empty"
    }
  },
  "metadata": "empty"
}
```

I have created the classes with objects with the same structure as the above JSON. I use the `retrofit` lib in Android which inside uses `GSON` for parsing the JSON.

My model classes would be like this:

**MResponse.class**

```
public class MResponse {

    @SerializedName("data")
    public User user;

    String metadata;
}
```

**User.class**

```
public class User {

    public String name;

    public String pid;

    @SerializedName("position")
    public PositionData positionData;
}
```

**PositionData.class**

```
public class PositionData {

    @SerializedName("data")
    public Position position;

    public String metadata;
}
```

**Position.class**

```
public class Position {

    public String x;

    public String y;
}
```

Now this works fine for me. But as you can see for every model I have to create a parent which will have the same structure just changes the child. This fact doubles the classes that I use for my models. I would like to ask if there is a better way to avoid all these classes.

I don't want to use inner classes. I was thinking that the guys that have done the JSON like this must have had a reason why they did it like this and also a way to make the parsing more easier.

Usually I was used to parse this kind of JSON structure:

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "Start",
    "pid": "1",
    "position": {
      "x": "31",
      "y": "330"
    }
  }
}
```

And here it's easier if I would follow the solution above.

EDIT

Also any solution in **Kotlin** is welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a generic container/entity for "data" and "metadata" and reuse it. e.g.:

```
data class MEntity<T>(
        var data: T? = null,
        var metadata: String? = null
)

data class User(
        var name: String? = null,
        var pid: String? = null,
        var position: MEntity<Position>? = null
)

data class Position(
        var x: String? = null,
        var y: String? = null
)
```

Due to type erasure you must use a [`TypeToken`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) to deserialize the JSON into a generic type:

```
gson.fromJson<MEntity<User>>(json, object : TypeToken<MEntity<User>>() {}.type)
```

This isn't very convenient but thankfully Kotlin allows us to use [reified type parameters](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) to define an [extension function](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) to simplify this:

```
inline fun <reified T> Gson.fromJsonToGeneric(json: String): T {
    return fromJson(json, object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type)
}
```

Now the usage becomes much simpler:

```
val userMEntity = gson.fromJsonToGeneric<MEntity<User>>(json)
println(userMEntity)
```

Output:

```
MEntity(data=User(name=Start, pid=1, position=MEntity(data=Position(x=31, y=330), metadata=empty)), metadata=empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the solution that I was asking for was quite simple in my opinion, I just didn't know it in the beginning. I found this times ago but now I want to write it here. I haven't used the `Kotlin` solution mentioned from `@mfulton` but I think that it's also the right answer.

Based on source code of `Retrofit` and some other related answers about `Java generics` this was the answer for my problem:

```
public class DataResponse<T, R> {

    public T data;

    @SerializedName("meta")
    public R metadata;
}
```

and this is an example how I can use it:

```
Observable<DataResponse<User, BaseMeta>> getUser()
```

For me this was the solution. If there are better solution out there, I am ready to accept them.